# Fast data transfer between a python program (server) and a Java program (client) on the same singleboard Linux computer (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: python, java, linux, raspberry-pi, gamepad

I know relativ good java and created a videogame using it for raspberry pi. The game must be controlled via an USB joystick. I searched and found many variant to read joystick data, but it seems that the best way is to use evdev written on python. How can I transfer data from a python script to a Java application? They are on the same raspberry pi with raspberry pi OS.

It seams that the best way is to create files using python and read they or the their names from my Java game. The files must be named so: 4_up_pressed.txt or
5_x+_035.txt
6_y-_075.txt
And so on. The first number is the number of a command. But I think that this way is not fast. Can I direct and fast transfer data from python into Java on the same Raspberry pi?

Comment: There are **many** ways to do this. Have a look into unix sockets or named pipes.

Comment: Why not use plain TCP sockets? You create a socket from the python to the java and just spew the commands. Remember to set the TCP_NODELAY option so that data is sent immediately.

Comment: I try to find the simplest for me and relative performance fast way to make it. I have 5 years Java experience but today I tried launch python at the first time and python seems to be very difficult for me. I don't want to learn python deep only for this task. I need to organize simple communication like: python get an event and an integer from it variable (x-axis shift on lleft to 75 percent = - 75) and transfers this data to a Java opened applet. But I think the simplest way for the beginner is to create files which will be readen from Java applet

Comment: What about [this](https://github.com/cyberp/simple-evdev-java)?

Comment: gOOse, I will try this solution. I think, It is the best, what can exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best was works perfect is the library :
[simple-evdev-java](https://github.com/cyberp/simple-evdev-java)
Thanks you gOOse.

But it is only a simple implementation of the python library. It has no ability to access the name of the connected devices (it must have low level access and an another library with c/c++ dependencies, I think). I can set up my app with my single Raspbery PI and my gamepad, but for every other device in the production batch I need to write a difficult agroritm to test which connected device from 10 is actually the joystick. It depends also from the number of connected devices. I think I will use the [simple-evdev-java](https://github.com/cyberp/simple-evdev-java) library for the "in game events", but I will run the original python evdev script to get the list of all the connected devices with their names. Than I save this data in a TXT file and I read it from the main java game at the game start. I think it must work if I can make the python script with the integrated evdev library executable.
The code should be so. It works from the PyCharm:

```
from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes, KeyEvent
path = '/dev/input/event'
i = 0
end = 20
dataForSave = ["" for x in range(end)]
for i in range(end):
    actualPath = path + str(i)
    try:
        gamepad = InputDevice(actualPath)
        stringForSaving = gamepad.name+'_x_'+actualPath
        dataForSave[i]=stringForSaving
    except:
         

with open('devices.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for i in range(len(dataForSave)):
        if (len(dataForSave[i]) > 1):
            output_file.write(dataForSave[i])
            output_file.write('\r')
print('ended')
```